# displaying image with imshow in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I construct an the image as follows

```
   import numpy
   im = numpy.zeros((100,100,3))
   im[:,:,0] = rdata
   im[:,:,1] = gdata
   im[:,:,2] = bdata
```

when I show this data using imshow as follows

```
  imshow(im)
```

It does not display correct result.

But if I do the following

```
  scipy.misc.imsave("temp.png",im)
  nimg = scipy.misc.imread("temp.png")
  imshow(nimg)
```

The image is displayed correctly.

I am not sure what is the issue, is there any type problem, like my data is mean normalized.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the `imshoe` is supposed to be `imshow`?

Comment: Hi it was a typo, i change it